# Why isn't the binomial distribution completely defined by its mean and variance?

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, simulation, sufficient-statistics

I'm currently reading Gelman and Hill (ARM) chapter 7 on simulation of probability models and statistical inferences. To motivate simulation of probability models, the authors explain that "if the estimate is normally distributed, this summary discards no information because the normal distribution is completely defined by its mean and variance". The authors proceed with an example where simulation is used to summarize inferences, using the binomial distribution.

Why isn't the binomial distribution also completely defined by its mean (np) and variance np(1-p)?

Comment: Typically with a binomial distribution you already know $n$ (the number of trials), so the only unknown parameter is $p$.  In this case, the binomial distribution is completely defined by its mean given knowledge of $n$, and the variance adds no information.

Comment: Thank you. I think the writers were providing a simple example of simulation in a situation where point estimates and stand errors could also be used. I had assumed that they were providing an example of a situation where simulation was necessary.

Comment: If you run Bernoulli trials you will of course know n and can estimate p. If you have the strange situation where you don't know data but you know the mean and variance because you have two equations in two unknowns you can determine n and p. So you can say that the binomial distribution is determined by its mean and variance.

Comment: A quick and easy way to answer questions of this sort is to look up the formula for any mathematical expression that determines the distribution.  In *every* case, the CDF or the characteristic function (cf) or the cumulant generating function (cgf) will work.  So, please visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution and refer to the formulas there, noticing that they all depend on variables $n,$ $p,$ *and nothing else.*

Answer (score 5):

[Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) can be defined by mean and the variance. Its conventional parameterization is with number of trials $n$ and the probability $p$. You can find them easily from the mean $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2$:
$$p=1-\sigma^2/\mu$$
$$n=\mu/p$$